# Can the 'range' function be assigned to a list?

Tags: python

I am studying the [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index) PDF. On page 82 i come across this question.

- Could you have avoided that for-loop entirely on line 23 and just assigned range(0,6) directly to elements?

Given the code:

```
# we can also build lists, first start with an empty one
elements = []

# then use the range function to do 0 to 20 counts
for i in range(0, 6):
    print "Adding %d to the list." % i    # line 23
    # append is a function that lists understand
    elements.append(i)

# now we can print them out too
for i in elements:
    print "Element was: %d" % i
```

It seems this is not possible unless i use the map function? Am i correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python 2.x, `range` returns a list. In 3.x, it returns an iterable range object. You can always use `list(range(...))` to get a list.

However, `for x in y` does not require `y` to be a list, just an iterable (such as `xrange`(2.x only), `range`, `list`, `str`, ...)

Answer (score 4):

But you can also do quite complex assignments as well.

```
elements = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

elements[3:5] = range(10,12) # replace indexes 3 and 4 with 10 and 11.

elements[3:7:2] = range(100,201,100) replace indexes 3 and 5 with 100 and 200

elements[:] = range(4) # replace entire list with [0,1,2,3]
```

[start,end,by] notation is called slicing. Start is the index to start at (inclusive, default is 0). End is the index to end (exclusive, default is len(list)). By is how to move from index to the next (default is 1)

Comment: Really? That sucks. Is there new syntax/functionality to make up for the loss?

Comment: Not true, all but the third statement work in Python 3.  The third only doesn't work because 200 needs to be replaced with 201 (or there's only one element in the range).

Comment: Oops, third statement wouldn't work in python 2.* either. Even said in my explanation that it wouldn't work. Anyway, fixed.

Comment: @Steve Howard: Oh, well, I'm wrong! I guess it makes sense that you can assign any iterable to a slice and it works. Doesn't make any sense at all to assign a single value to a slice. Sorry about that @Dune. *sheepish grin*

Answer (score 2):

The hint is probably meant to suggest that you could have simply used

```
elements = range(6)
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

elements = range(0,6)

It is an implicit list.

Comment: Thank you (all of you). I was thinking too difficult.

Comment: @Bas van der Zon - This answer is only correct in Python 2.x, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = range(0,5)
elements.extend(range(5, 10))
#elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[More on extend](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)